# How to ensure all threads stop when Flask restarts in debug mode

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a (Python) Flask server. In the background I have a thread which is acquiring data from a hardware device. When I run in debug mode, Flask restarts the server ("* Restarting with stat") as expected.

I've added a timestamp logging debug feature to the thread. It shows me that the logged timestamps are not monotonic, but if I run with debug=False, the code behaves as expected: the timestamps only increase.

I suspected that my acquisition thread was not being stopped, so with the code still running, I modified the source to print an additional "*" in the log file. As expected, when I saved it, it automagically re-runs. If I look at the log file, some of the logs are being written with the "*" and some are not, illustrating that the old thread is still running.

How can I ensure that Flask stops my threads when it does a rerun in debug mode?